# What slow fuse should I get?

Tags: fuses

I had a fuse go in our old microscope. It says 125V 3 amperes on the top of the fuse. It is a slow fuse. This is what the broken one looks like. I have not been able to find the same part in my searching. Grainger sent me to a different style when I contacted them for parts but that mentions 250V.

https://www.grainger.com/product/MERSEN-Fuse-3-A-5LAU5?internalSearchTerm=5LAU5&suggestConfigId=8&searchBar=true&opr=THKS&position=1

[image]

Comment: Rated voltage of the fuse doesn't matter as long as it's higher than the old one,

Comment: What are all the other markings on the fuse? As DK says, higher voltage is okay. Probably 3.15A is okay too.

Comment: If properly spec'd, fuses don't tend to "wear out".  While you have things apart, look for additional signs/issues that would have caused the fuse to blow.

Comment: Is it just me, or the fuse doesn't look blown on the photo?

Comment: "the fuse doesn't look blown on the photo" It does if you can zoom in to the photo. It is open circuit close to the bottom of the glass section.

Comment: It might be an illusion, but to me the fuse you're holding looks proportionally longer than "typical".  Grangier sent you a 'standard/typical' size fuse.  If what you have is longer/thicker/whatever,   and you can't match it, you may have to replace the fuse holder with something that holds a standard size fuse - in which case the Granger ones would work fine.   This isn't a daunting task for one mechanically inclined.  How old is the microscope.. like 1940's old maybe???

Comment: It is a JEOL 845A Scanning electron scope from the 70s. It has been refurbished then my company bought it. I don't know if the fuse had ever been changed. The wires on one end are not connected anymore. After some consulting I managed to find a time-delay fuse from Ace hardware 250V 3A that worked thankfully. I have it in the ion pump of the scope and all seems good so far!